# Improve performance of DataSet.InitClass

Tags: vb.net, performance, dataset

I inherited a giant dataset that my profiler notes that the InitClass method takes over 5 seconds to load.

This is generated code so, other than removing unneeded datatables etc...  is there anything I can do to improve the performance of this method?

This is in VB.NET

**EDIT**

The profiler says that 99% of the time is spent inside the method itself, I looked at this method and it adds 14 tables and their relationships.

I'm using the EQATEC free profiler (version 3.0.46) and it's not telling me which line is taking the longest, only that the there are 30 method calls in the InitClass method and they take <1% of the time spent.

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming language you are using.

Comment: What is `InitClass` doing that takes 5 seconds? (Expand it in the profiler)